# FTP Windows 10 -- How to conclusively know you're in non-interactive mode?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ftp

I'm having trouble with the "prompt" command in FTP.

Bottom line--is there a command that says "don't prompt me" that is *NOT* a toggle?

By this I mean that I seem to be seeing is that the "default" doesn't always seem to be what I expected (this is all automated script processing btw).  So if I have a set of commands in the script:

```
lcd C:\SomeLocalFolder
binary
mget *.xyz
```

and everything worked--it seemed to default to no-prompt.  Now it seems to require me to specifically put in a prompt command to toggle the prompt off.

I'd like a command that says "I don't care if prompt is already off or on--turn off the prompt regardless!"

Comment: Use `ftp -i` Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.